# Pushing Messages From BlazeDs to Flex (Invoking within Java)

Tags: java, apache-flex, tomcat, messaging, blazeds

I'm having trouble figuring out how to simply send a message via BlazeDs(On Tomcat) to a Flex client. I have it working to send/receive a message from the client, but I have a situation where I need to send a message originating in Java. I thought this would be much easier.

Methods I have tried:

- MessageService.pushMessageToClients(msg);
- ServiceAdapter.invoke(msg);

  > Exception: flex.messaging.MessageException: java.lang.NullPointerException : null
- MessageBroker.routeMessageToService(msg);

  > [BlazeDS]14:03:35.898 Exception when invoking service: (none) with message: Flex Message (flex.messaging.messages.AsyncMessage)

> **SERVICES.XML:**

```
<channel-definition id="my-streaming-amf"
    class="mx.messaging.channels.StreamingAMFChannel">
    <endpoint url="http://192.168.2.43:8400/testdrive/messagebroker/streamingamf"
    class="flex.messaging.endpoints.StreamingAMFEndpoint"/>
</channel-definition>
```

> **MESSAGE-CONFIG.XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<adapters>

    <adapter-definition id="actionscript" class="flex.messaging.services.messaging.adapters.ActionScriptAdapter" default="false" />

    <adapter-definition id="AMFMessageAdapter" class="services.AMFMessageAdapter" default="true" />

   <!-- <adapter-definition id="jms" class="flex.messaging.services.messaging.adapters.JMSAdapter"/> -->

</adapters>

<default-channels>
    <channel ref="my-streaming-amf"/>
</default-channels>

<destination id="AMFMessageAdapterDestination">
    <channels>
        <channel ref="my-streaming-amf" />
    </channels>
    <adapter ref="AMFMessageAdapter" />
</destination>
```

> **AMFMessageAdapter**

```
package services;

import flex.messaging.messages.AsyncMessage;
import flex.messaging.messages.Message;
import flex.messaging.services.MessageService;
import flex.messaging.services.ServiceAdapter;

/**
 * Test service adapter.  Great for testing when you want to JUST SEND AN OBJECT and nothing
 * else.  This class has to stay in the main codebase (instead of test) because, when it's used
 * it needs to be deployed to Tomcat.
 * @author Kevin G
 *
 */

public class AMFMessageAdapter extends ServiceAdapter {

    String testMessage = "TEST_MESSAGE";

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Message message) {
            AsyncMessage newMessage = (AsyncMessage) message;
        newMessage.setBody(testMessage);
        MessageService msgService = (MessageService)getDestination().getService();
        msgService.pushMessageToClients(newMessage, false);
        return null;
    }

}
```

Any ideas folks?